# need help a query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I have doubt in sql server

```
Table : patient
patientno   | refdoctor| loccode | status | sdate
100         |  31      |10       | 1      | 2012-05-03 
100         | 32       |10       | 1      |1997-02-04
100         | 36       |10       | 1      |2014-09-16
100         |35        |10       | 1      |2013-05-03
100         | 50       |10       | 1      | 1988-05-08
100         | 20       |10       | 2      |2015-02-05

Table : targetpatient

patientno   | refdoctor| loccode | status | sdate
100         | 21       | 10      | 2      | 2004-05-18
100         | 23       | 10      | 2      |2005-07-25
100         | 24       | 10      | 2      | 2006-06-22
100         | 26       | 10      | 2      |2012-05-14
100         | 28       |10       | 2      |2013-05-03
100         |29        |10       | 2      | 2014-09-26
100         | 33       | 10      | 2      | 2012-10-22
100         | 39       | 10      | 2      |2002-12-13
100         |41        | 10      | 2      |2012-05-13
```

Here I want output patient table relates status

statusvalue=5's sdate is less than or equal to checkvalue=2's sdate and
the difference between the dates should be less than 30days then given count
if that condition not fall then count must be return zero(0)

```
select  o.patientno,o.loccode,o.status,o.sDate, count(*) as cnt
from patient o join targetpatient t on o.patientno=t.patientno and o.loccode=t.loccode and o.status in('1') and t.status in('2') and 
o.sDate<=t.sdate
and datediff(dd,o.sdate,t.sdate)<=30
group by o.patientno,o.loccode,o.status,o.sDate

based on above query I got result like below:

patientno   |  loccode | status | sdate      | count
100         | 10       |  1     |2012-05-03  | 2
100         | 10       | 1      |2013-05-03  | 1
100          | 10      | 1      |2014-09-16  | 1

but I want expected result like below 

patientno   |  loccode | status | sdate      | count
100         | 10       |  1     |2012-05-03  | 2
100         | 10       | 1      |2013-05-03  | 1
100         | 10       | 1      |2014-09-16  | 1
100         | 10       | 1      | 1997-02-04 | 0
100         | 10       |1       | 1988-05-08 | 0
```

please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the records that doesn't have any matches in the joined table you'll want to use a `left join` instead and do the `count` on a column in the joined table instead like this:

```
select o.patientno,o.loccode,o.status,o.sDate, count(t.sdate) as cnt
from patient o 
left join targetpatient t on o.patientno = t.patientno 
                         and o.loccode = t.loccode 
                         and o.status in('1') 
                         and t.status in('2') 
                         and o.sDate <= t.sdate
                         and datediff(dd,o.sdate,t.sdate) <= 30
group by o.patientno,o.loccode,o.status,o.sDate
```

A `left join` will return all rows from the table on the left side (`patient` in your case) plus the matching rows from the right-hand side table. The rows that doesn't have any matches in the right-hand side table will get null as values.

Comment: @user5509775 I'm afraid I don't understand. The query I provided gives the result that you used as an example (before you edited the question). Is this not correct?